# How can I download original-sized bigger pictures from website en masse?

Tags: download

I don't want click each picture on [Zimbio](http://www.zimbio.com/photos/Jacquelyn+Jablonski/browse) to load original bigger size - way too unproductive! But if downloading that page will download just the small thumbnails.

I installed Chrome, Firefox, Opera on my laptop. I can use which-ever one is easier.

Comment: you would need a third party extension similar to this....https://www.pcsteps.com/5170-mass-download-images-chrome/

Comment: What browser are you using?  This will require an extension, and those are browser-specific, unless you are willing to use any browser for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Manual solution:**

1. Install [Double-click image downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/double-click-image-download/). I tested it in Firefox but it's also available for Chrome
2. Start at image 1 in the gallery and click on the gallery image itself (not the next-image arrow). The browser will move to image 2 in the gallery, while the plugin dumps the first image in your download folder
3. Repeat step #2 257 times!  I timed it and it only took 5 minutes for every 100 images. You get everything you want, but also no banners, thumbnails or other irrelevant images that you don't want.
4. There were a few duplicates (the website's fault), so run [Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder](https://www.duplicate-finder.com/photo-download.html) on your download folder and remote any 100% duplicate matches (there were around a dozen duplicates of that model in the gallery)

This approach is basically just a manual download process, with three fewer mouse clicks per image thanks to an add-on. This makes a difference. Instead of four mouse clicks per image, you only need to do one per image. Click. Wait 3 seconds for the gallery to load the next image. Click. Etc.

This isn't too bad for a one-off task but if you need to do it a lot, someone with scripting skills will need to help you.

[image: totally relevant image]

**Better solution:**

If you download *all images* from that website using a script, then you could search for the model's last name in the downloaded images to find them. The main downside of this approach is it might take a very long time to download all images from the site.

**Even better solution:**

Use a script to download all image files on that website that contain the model's name. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that but I'm sure others here could help with that.

Comment: hi again! any time for fine tuning?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay. I'll check it out this weekend. Probably Sunday because I'm working Saturday. This is a tricky one!

Comment: no problem. take your time. i'm not in a rush.

Comment: @DongmeiMayWang This was harder than I expected. The challenge is that the website has directory browsing disabled, so we can't easily target just Jacquelyn Jablonski. Many irrelevant images keep getting included. Maybe someone else can post some ideas. There are scripts that can download *everything* but you would still need to manually pick out the images that you wanted, which isn't easy as some photos don't show Jacquelyn's face! I'm struggling to find an effective solution that's actually better than downloading all 247 images manually!

Comment: @DongmeiMayWang here's a temporary download link to a zip file I made with the images from that gallery: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj1dxauGLJPbgQiGbypoLRGqIOE7?e=BVgYgQ You'll want to extract this zip file so you can see the thumbnails.